Excel VBA match data from colum in two different workbooks and copy data to next blank Colum
I have two different workbooks, order and database. I need a VBA script that will match row data from column B and Colum G in each workbook and then copy an cell from order to database in next blank colum,
Sub macro1()

Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim iLastRow As Long, r As Long
Dim dict As Object, key As String, ar
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' build lookup from sheet2
Set w2 = Workbooks("Itimat-Bestellung.xlsm").Worksheets("itimat")
iLastRow = w2.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
ar = w2.Range("B4:D" & iLastRow).Value2

For r = 1 To UBound(ar)
    key = ar(r, 1) & vbTab & ar(r, 2)
    If Len(key) > 1 Then ' skip blanks
        If dict.exists(key) Then
            MsgBox "Duplicate key '" & key & "'", vbCritical, "Row " & r
            Exit Sub
        Else
            dict.Add key, ar(r, 3)
        End If
    End If
Next

' update sheet1
Set w1 = Workbooks("Itimat-Bestellung.xlsm").Worksheets("datenbank")
iLastRow = w1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For r = 2 To iLastRow
    key = w1.Cells(r, "A") & vbTab & w1.Cells(r, "B")
    If dict.exists(key) Then
        w1.Cells(r, "C") = dict(key)
    End If
Next
MsgBox "Data Saved in Database"

End Sub
to better understand put a pic of both sheets
first order Sheet second Database Sheet

|   | 11011 | Chicken   Dönerspieß                    Kg. | 5   | Stk. | 24320 |   | Hot Wings        (85-95Stk.)                5 Kg  |   | Btl. |
|---|-------|---------------------------------------------|-----|------|-------|---|---------------------------------------------------|---|------|
|   | 11012 | Chicken   Dönerspieß                    Kg. |     | Stk. | 29510 |   | Steak Bites       (65-75Stk.)                5 Kg |   | Btl. |
|   | 11010 | Chicken   Dönerspieß                 Kg.    | 5   | Stk. | 21310 |   | Tender Filet     (145-155Stk.)             5 Kg   |   | Btl. |
|   | 11025 | Chickenburger   (11x990g)                   | 999 | Krt  | 63210 |   | Coca Cola PET   (12x0,5l)                         |   | Pck  |
|   | 11060 | Chicken Schnitzel   Prem. (3Kg)22x140g      | 777 | Krt  | 63230 |   | Fanta PET (12x0,5l)                               |   | Pck  |
|   | 11080 | Chicken Nuggets Prem.   (16x700g)           |     | Krt  | 63240 |   | Sprite PET (12x0,5l)                              |   | Pck  |
|   | 12025 | Rind Hamburger 45g   (100 Stk.)             | 7   | Krt  | 63250 |   | Mezzo Mix PET   (12x0,5l)                         |   | Pck  |
|   | 13015 | Pommes 9mm  (4x2,5kg)                       |     | Krt  | 63260 |   | Lift Apfelschorle PET   (12x0,5l)                 |   | Pck  |
|   | 31081 | Falafel 12x1 Kg                             |     | Krt  | 63280 |   | Coca Cola Zero PET   (12x0,5l)                    |   | Pck  |
|   | 14010 | Hamburger Brot 57g   (48 Stk)               | 9   | Krt  | 63610 |   | FuzeTea Pfirsich PET   (12x0,5l)                  |   | Pck  |
|   | 14320 | Tortilla Brot 25cm   (18 Stk.)              |     | Krt  | 63630 |   | FuzeTea Hibiskus PET   (12x0,5l)                  |   | Pck  |


You can accomplish the same task much easier and likely faster in Power Query.  Does it have to be a VBA solution?

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.

@taller hope this help

Your code is close to finish. Add a few lines of code to load Artk from column G (marked with **), similar to the first part of your script.
Sub macro1()

    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long, r As Long
    Dim dict As Object, key As String, ar
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' build lookup from sheet2
    Set w2 = Workbooks("Itimat-Bestellung.xlsm").Worksheets("itimat")
    iLastRow = w2.Cells(w2.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    ar = w2.Range("B4:D" & iLastRow).Value

    For r = 1 To UBound(ar)
        key = ar(r, 1) & vbTab & ar(r, 2)
        If Len(key) > 1 Then ' skip blanks
            If dict.exists(key) Then
                MsgBox "Duplicate key '" & key & "'", vbCritical, "Row " & r
                Exit Sub
            Else
                dict.Add key, ar(r, 3)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ' *** load Artk from Col G 
    iLastRow = w2.Cells(w2.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    ar = w2.Range("G4:I" & iLastRow).Value
    For r = 1 To UBound(ar)
        key = ar(r, 1) & vbTab & ar(r, 2)
        If Len(key) > 1 Then ' skip blanks
            If dict.exists(key) Then
                MsgBox "Duplicate key '" & key & "'", vbCritical, "Row " & r
                Exit Sub
            Else
                dict.Add key, ar(r, 3)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ' ***

    ' update sheet1
    Set w1 = Workbooks("Itimat-Bestellung.xlsm").Worksheets("datenbank")
    iLastRow = w1.Cells(w1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ' ***
    Dim iLastCol As Long
    iLastCol = w1.Cells(1, w1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    With w1.Cells(1, iLastCol + 1)
        .NumberFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
        .Value = Date
    End With
    ' ***
    For r = 2 To iLastRow
        key = w1.Cells(r, "A") & vbTab & w1.Cells(r, "B")
        If dict.exists(key) Then
            w1.Cells(r, iLastCol + 1) = dict(key)
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "Data Saved in Database"

End Sub


thx for this but how can i put  the value every time the script rund in next   new Colum of database sheet

I've updated the last part of script.

its do noting in database script...

What's does do noting mean?

my mistake the sheet have some colum in AE-AM so the post start on AO .. fixed.. thx for your help
